# C++ custom read function return wrong values for the first two files inside a folder

Tags: c++

So my problem is this, I have a folder, with ".dat" files containing numerical values for a calculated spectrum. Each data file has a set number of lines and columns.

Using this code, for the first two files that the function opens, i get the wrong value for the number of lines inside the data files.

This is my code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getdir(string, vector<string>&);
int getsize(vector<string>&, vector<int>&);

int main(){
    string dir = string("input");
    vector<string> files = vector<string>();
    vector<int> filesize = vector<int>();

    getdir(dir,files);
    getsize(files, filesize);

    return 0;
}

int getdir (string path, vector<string> &files){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    if((dir  = opendir(path.c_str())) == NULL) {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << path << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(entry->d_name, "." ) == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, ".." ) == 0 ){
            continue;
        }
        //cout<<entry->d_name<<endl;
        files.push_back(string(entry->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}

int getsize(vector<string> &filename, vector<int> &filesize){
    ifstream *read = new ifstream[filename.size()];
    string *f = new string[filename.size()];
    string *line = new string[filename.size()];

    int *numlines = new int[filename.size()];

    sort(filename.begin(), filename.end());

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<filename.size(); i++){
        f[i] = "input/"+filename[i];
        read[i].open(f[i].c_str(), ios::in);

        cout<<"File["<<i<<"] "<<filename[i]<<endl;
        while(read[i].good()){
            getline(read[i], line[i]);
            ++numlines[i];
        }

        filesize.push_back(numlines[i]);
        cout<<filesize[i]<<endl;
        read[i].close();
    }
    delete[] f;
    delete[] line;
    delete[] read;
    delete[] numlines;
}
```

Not being able to upload images, my results are as follow:

```
File[0] filename1.dat
5518348
File[1] filename2.dat
5510484
File[2] filename3.dat
108
File[3] filename4.dat
108
.
.
```

Any suggestion on what might i do to get a correct reading? 
Thank you for your help and feedback.

Have a good one.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting vs the output you are seeing and is there any correlation between them?

Comment: In this case, the function should return 108 for all files. But as stated, the first 2 files (filename1.dat and filename2.dat) always return a random value. I should restate that all files have a standard format (same number of lines, same number of columns, basically, the files are identical, except the values inside them)

Comment: You aren't initializing the contents of the `numlines` array.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have solved it. Rooky mistake. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
int *numlines = new int[filename.size()];
```

you never initialize the values, so they start off as garbage. To explain your results, probably what happened is that the first two entries had large garbage values and the later entries had `0` by chance.

To fix this you could write:

```
int *numlines = new int[filename.size()]();
```

or you could set `numlines[i]` to `0` before using it.

However I would strongly consider getting rid of all those arrays (that's crazy, TBH). Just declare one of each thing inside your `i` loop.